# SQL Grabbing unque counts per category

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm pretty new to SQL and Redshift, but there is a weird problem I'm getting.
So my data looks like below. Ignore id, date_time actual values... I just put random info, but its the same format

`id date_time(var char 255)
 1  2019-01-11T05:01:59
 1  2019-01-11T05:01:59
 2  2019-01-11T05:01:59
 3  2019-01-11T05:01:59
 1  2019-02-11T05:01:59
 2  2019-02-11T05:01:59`

I'm trying to get the number of counts of unique ID's per month.
I've tried the following command below. Given the amount of data, I just tried to do a demo of the first 10 rows of my table...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id),
       LEFT(date_time,7)
FROM    ( SELECT top 10* 
         FROM myTable.ME )
GROUP BY LEFT(date_time, 7), id
```

I expect something like below.

`count    left
3       2019-01
2      2019-02`

But I'm instead getting similar to what's below

[image]

I then tried the below command which seems correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id),
       LEFT(date_time,7)
FROM    ( SELECT top 1000000*
          FROM myTable.ME )
GROUP BY LEFT(date_time, 7)
```

However, if you remove the DISTINCT portion, you get the results below. It seems like it is only looking at a certain month (2019-01), rather than other months.
[image]

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with the commands I'm using or can give me the correct command, I'll be very grateful. Thank you.
EDIT: Could it possibly be because maybe my data isn't clean?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a string for the date?  That is simply wrong.  There are built-in types.  But assuming you have some reason or cannot change it, use string functions:

```
select left(date_time, 7) as yyyymm,
       count(distinct id)
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

In your first query you have `id` in the `group by` which does not do what you want.